# Array going out of range?

Tags: vbscript, device

I have a device related vbscript problem. The code below is not even supposed to execute after `i = playercount` but it does.

```
Do Until i = playercount

    If i = playercount then
        Exit Do
    end if

    Select Case True
        Case i >=1 And i <= 4
            'usb hubs 1-4
            'b = i + 1
             If pluggedindev(4) = False Then

                   msgbox(i)
                   msgbox(playercount)
                   Set ExtHubPort(i) = ExtHub(1).Ports(i)
                   Wscript.Sleep 2000
                   ExtHubPort(i).HotPlug GenericHIDDSFDev(i)
                   WScript.Sleep 10000
                   pluggedindev(i) = True
                   MsgBox("usb device (ports 1-4)")
             'else if playercount <= 4 then
                   'Exit Do
             End If

        Case i >=5 And i <= 8
            'usb hubs 5-8
            Wscript.sleep 2000

            For b = 1 To 4
                 Set ExtHubPort(i) = ExtHub(2).Ports(b)
                 Wscript.sleep 2000
                 ExtHubPort(i).HotPlug GenericHIDDSFDev(i)
                 WScript.Sleep 10000
                 'Log("Usb devices 1 through 4 set")
            Next 

            'usb hubs 9-12
        Case i >=9 And i <= 12
            For b = 1 To 4 
            Set ExtHubPort(i) = ExtHub(3).Ports(b)
                Wscript.sleep 2000
                ExtHubPort(i).HotPlug GenericHIDDSFDev(i)
                WScript.Sleep 10000
            Next 
           'usb hubs 13-16
        Case i >=13 And i <= 16
            For b = 1 To 4 
                Set ExtHubPort(i) = ExtHub(4).Ports(b)
                Wscript.sleep 2000
                ExtHubPort(i).HotPlug GenericHIDDSFDev(i)
                WScript.Sleep 10000
            Next 
         'usb hubs 17-20
        Case i >=17 And i <=20
            For b = 1 To 4 
                Set ExtHubPort(i) = ExtHub(5).Ports(b)
                Wscript.sleep 2000
                ExtHubPort(i).HotPlug GenericHIDDSFDev(i)
                WScript.Sleep 10000
            Next 
    End Select

    i = i + 1

Loop
```

Anyone take a look and see why?
It appears that i subscript is going out of range and causing the problem but clearly the code above is supposed to work.

Comment: what are `i` and `playercount` initialised to?

Comment: playercount is given a test value of 4 and keeps going into 5 instead of stopping. Maybe counter keeps adding when it reach's 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out as the comment about the value of I or playercount was correct. I solved it by putting this code at the end of the loop forcing the counter to stop before it reached playercount (it stopped at 4?). variable i just keep on going up because my if and other statements where not used correctly. Thanks for all who helped.

```
If i = playercount  then
Exit Do
elseif i < playercount then
i = i + 1
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you start with a playercount of 0 (zero) and initializes i at 1 (one). The `i = playercount` condition will never be met, presenting you with errors when it goes into the second iteration of your original loop.

For a starter, shorten your code to something like this:

```
' Let ExtHubPort(1 to playercount) reference to
'     ExtHub(1 to playercount/4).Ports(1 to 4)
For i = 0 to playercount - 1
    Set ExtHubPort(i+1) = ExtHub(int(i/4)+1).Ports((i mod 4) + 1)
    Wscript.sleep 2000
    ExtHubPort(i+1).HotPlug GenericHIDDSFDev(i+1)
    WScript.Sleep 10000
Next
```

Now it is easier to see at what part of the loop it is going wrong.

Comment: I put a message box to show me the count of i and playercount. But after i = playercount it continues and should not.

Comment: ExtHub(hubnumber).Ports(specific port number on hub)

Comment: I will have try code but ExtHub can start at 0 but Ports has to be a value from 1 to 4 since I cannot figure out how to make the virtual usb hub support more ports.